# Why is this returning "NO"?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, dictionary

I am working through "The HackerRank Interview Preparation Kit" and have stumbled across this solution by another user.
The solution is incorrect and HackerRank accepts it as "correct", I want to understand why.

```
// find if there is a common substring
string twoStrings(string s1, string s2)
{
    int n;
    int m;
    const char* char_array1;
    const char* char_array2;
    unordered_map<char, char> map;

    n = s1.size();
    m = s2.size();
    char_array1 = s1.c_str();
    char_array2 = s2.c_str();

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        map[char_array1[i]] = char_array1[i + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        if (map[char_array2[i]] != 0)
            return "YES";

    return "NO";
}
```

The values I am passing in are:

```
beetroots & sandals
```

The code returns "NO" which is incorrect as 's' appears in both words.

Comment: I guess it is because the testset on HackerRank was not strong enough.

Comment: Do you have a link to it on HackerRank?

Comment: I guess they do not have a testcase when only last symbol in the first string matches one in the second, and this function fails only for that.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this returning “NO”?

The function returns `"NO"` because the first loop which populates `map` does not consider the last character of `s1` - so immediately before the second `for` starts, the `map` will contain entries for `b`, `e`, `t`, `r`, and `o`:

```
map['b'] = 'e'
map['e'] = 't'
map['t'] = 's'
map['r'] = 'o'
map['o'] = 't'
```

I suspect the author of this code thought that `basic_string::size()` returns the number of elements in the underlying character array (i.e. including the null-terminator `\0`) - but in actually returns the number of characters (well, the number of elements, which are not necessarily characters depending on the encoding being used).

The function itself is completely wrong because it doesn't perform any logic relating to checking for common substrings - it just checks to see if any character in `s2` exists in `s1` (except the last character of `s1`).

> The solution is incorrect and HackerRank accepts it as "correct", I want to understand why.

The only cause for this that I can think of it that HackerRank is using an inadequate set of test-cases - which is unusual because they tend to be good at this sort of thing.

Comment: Actually function is almost right, they are fine with "substring" one symbol length. So to catch this they need to create a very specific test case

Comment: "I suspect the author of this code thought that" I don't think so, author used `n-1` because he/she uses `char_array1[i + 1]` on the right side of assignment. Though why it is done this way complete enigma.

Comment: @Slava yes this is what I've found, the last character is omitted, and I'm guessing the value set of the data is just added to allow for a valid map object.
I've found if I go through and change ```n = s1.size()```  and ```m = s2.size()``` to ```length()```, and update the for loops to be ```for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)``` and ```for (int i = 0; i < m+1; i++)```. It allows both strings to be compared, I think. Still, I have no clue why the last if statement ```!= 0``` works, I guess I have to research maps more.
Thanks for the help guys, I will update if I figure it out.

Comment: wait actually size and length are the same